# Granular permissions in Yandex Cloud Object Storage

Tags: yandexcloud

How to create a service account in Object Storage that has permissions only for one bucket?

I've tried to create service account via Web Console, but can't find any roles related to Object Storage:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict access for a service account, you need to use [ACL](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/storage/concepts/acl).

You'll also need to use [YC CLI](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/cli/) and [AWS CLI](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/storage/instruments/aws-cli).

Let me explain everything from the beginning starting with account creation.

```
# yc iam service-account create name <account name>
id: <service-account id>
folder_id: <folder_id>
created_at: "2019-01-23T45:67:89Z"
name: <account name>

# yc iam access-key create service-account-name <account name>
access_key:
id: <operation id>
service_account_id: <service-account_id>
created_at: "2019-12-34T56:78:90Z"
key_id: <key id>
secret: <secret key>
```

Save the key_id and the secret key. Now set the AWS CLI according to the instruction in [documentation](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/storage/instruments/aws-cli) to work from the admin service account.

Create a bucket and set access for it. To grant access, you need to set the `service_account_id` in the `put-bucket-acl` command of the `id` field.

```
# aws endpoint-url=https://storage.yandexcloud.net s3  
mb s3://<bucket_name>
make_bucket: <bucket_name>

# aws endpoint-url=https://storage.yandexcloud.net 
s3api put-bucket-acl \
bucket hidden-bucket grant-full-control 
id=<service_account_id> \
grant-read
```

P.S. The only problem is that Yandex Object storage doesn't support permission "WRITE", and you can only set full-access for a service account. It means it can edit ACL on its bucket.